# Is "Annular Ring" redundant?

Tags: calculus, geometry, terminology

I've come across the term *annular ring* in parentheses following *washer* in my calculus textbook: "has the shape of a washer (an annular ring)". The definition of the word "annular" in [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/annular) is "of, relating to, or forming a ring". With that, the term *annular ring* seems redundant to me. A Google search of the phrase returns around 946,000 results, and leads me to question my conclusion.

From what I have found, it appears that [annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)) would have been a more appropriate choice by the author of this textbook, as that is what the shape in question represents.

Is this usage redundant, or have I missed a subtlety in its usage? For example, does mathematics (especially in calculus and/or geometry) provide for non-annular rings? If so, what distinguishes a ring that is annular from a ring that is not annular but still qualifies as a ring?

Comment: You cannot ask general speakers of English about whether a technical usage in a specialized field is "redundant".

Comment: @GEdgar Despite the context, this felt general enough in the sense that its use is simply to describe a washer.

Comment: Aren't you asking whether we need to tell people they're wrong and that they have to stop talking that way? Please explain why you think redundancy is a problem. It is not. It is a valuable feature. How else would someone distinguish an annular ring from a campanal ring from a criminal ring?

Comment: I'd agree that 'annulus' and 'annular ring' both exist, are quite widely used, and have a considerable overlap in meaning. I'd probably have chosen 'annulus' for a maths textbook but 'annular ring' when talking about PCB manufacture. But this is largely non-standard–everyday English (better asked on Mathematics, say) and opinionative.

Comment: Redundancy is not a defect. Language is over 90% redundant; it's one of the design features because it allows communication with imperfect transmission, which is the norm.

Comment: @tchrist That argument feels akin to always qualifying "circle" with round: "a car tire is a round circle", to distinguish from phrases such as "a circle of friends". In this case, the context of this being a 'washer' shape tells us what definition of ring should be applied.

Comment: I'm happy to delete the question, but am genuinely curious about this: While in a technical book, we're comparing to a 'washer' shape which seems generic enough. I do understand that redundancy is not abnormal, but this case seemed overly so, but it seems I'm mistaken, or as Edwin says, this is opinion based.

Comment: I just saw that there are different types of rings in various branches of mathematics, and annular ring is one of them.

Comment: @Lambie But mathematical rings aren't like physical rings -- they aren't circular, so it's not redundant in that case.

Comment: If you drew a small circle on the open face of a tree stump- much smaller than the tree diameter and off center, it’d still be a ring but it wouldn’t be an annular ring.

Comment: I think it's important to keep in mind the audience of a calculus text. For a large minority (maybe even a majority) of the intended readers, the word "annulus" is probably not going to help much in clarifying what is meant by "washer". As for redundancy, "ring" by itself is probably not descriptive enough, and the point of saying "annular ring" is not to establish terminology (I strongly suspect "washer" is the term the book uses) but to clarify the meaning of "washer", and "annular ring" does this better than "ring". Speaking of redundancy, "straight line" didn't use to be redundant.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro good point. Btw, how did “line” come to automatically mean straight line?

Comment: @ryang: I don't know when "line" clearly meant "straight line" began, but I do know that in 1800s literature the word "line" was generally used for planar curves in general (usually algebraic curves, although "usually" here probably because non-algebraic curves were rarely investigated to any great extent).

Comment: Rings can either be annular (like a UFO) or tubular (like a superbowl ring) or just a band (like a rubberband). So an annular ring simply means that it is not the other two types

Comment: The word "ring" alone would not be sufficient (even in the context of mathematics), but, as far as I know, "annulus" alone would be sufficient.

Comment: My question is, is entering inside an annular ring part and parcel with rising above the facts and circumstances of effective best practices in teaching pedagogy with care and attention to scholastic inquiry, or is it a violation of the terms and conditions and part and parcel to high crimes and misdemeanors?

Comment: I think it’s a pity this was migrated from EL&U, because there’s an interesting double standard at work here. Saying “round circle” is redundant—all circles are round. Saying “circular shape” (where “circular” isn’t taken as implying “approximately”) is also redundant—all circles are shapes. And yet I would not react nearly as negatively to the second as I would to the first! (And then does “annular ring” fit in the first category, or the second, or neither?)

Comment: @DaveLRenfro and, in the 1980's, it was pounded into my head multiple times a week that a *line* was *infinite* and had to be drawn with those little arrows on each side to indicate it. A line with two endpoints in finite space was a "line segment", and what would otherwise be called a "vector" was a "ray".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I argue that *annular ring* is not redundant because in common use *annulus* and *ring* are not synonyms. Put another way, not all rings are annular.

The adjective *annular* is used to emphasize that the ring in question is flat in the sense of being close to planar.

In colloquial use a *ring* is something tubular (like a donut). That is, a section in a plane crossed by the tube is roughly circular. While *annulus* has no colloquial use, it generally means something approximating the planar region delimited by two concentric circles. That is, a section in a plane crossed by the tube is roughly a short, wide rectangle. Together an *annular ring* denominates a sort of flattened tube - that is a washer.

The terminology *annular ring* is common in electronics where it is used to refer to the ring of copper around a hole drilled through the copper pad on a (generally flat) circuit board.

Comment: The "annular ring" in electronics is the ring of copper left after you drill the hole in the copper pad for the component lead to pass through.

Comment: @JRE: This is what I was trying to write - I've tried to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps "formally redundant", depending on who you ask. As in the many comments. But/and a certain amount of redundancy can be good, if it saves time and confusion. "Let me repeat that in different words..." :)

In the classes I teach, I do try to explain the sense in which I'll use words, pretending to avoid having to explain at-the-moment, but I do invariably explain at-the-moment also, ... *and* meta-explain that setting context is surely inescapable for genuine technical communication.

So, yeah, maybe some people would find it redundant, but, manifestly, not everyone. And, apart from the time spent talking about whether it's redundant, it is more efficient to be slightly redundant, to avoid confusion. :)